# how can I speed up my queries?

Tags: mysql

so I have a 560mb db with the largest table 500mb(over 10 million rows)

my query hase to join 5 tables and takes about 10 seconds to finish....

```
SELECT DISTINCT trips.tripid                                AS tripid,
                stops.stopdescrption                        AS "perron",
                Date_format(segments.segmentstart, "%H:%i") AS "time",
                Date_format(trips.tripend, "%H:%i")         AS "arrival",
                Upper(routes.routepublicidentifier)         AS "lijn",
                plcend.placedescrption                      AS "destination"
FROM   calendar
       JOIN trips
         ON calendar.vsid = trips.vsid
       JOIN routes
         ON routes.routeid = trips.routeid
       JOIN places plcstart
         ON plcstart.placeid = trips.placeidstart
       JOIN places plcend
         ON plcend.placeid = trips.placeidend
       JOIN segments
         ON segments.tripid = trips.tripid
       JOIN stops
         ON segments.stopid = stops.stopid
WHERE  stops.stopid IN ( 43914, 23899, 23925, 23908,
                         23913, 19899, 23871, 43902,
                         23876, 25563, 18956, 19912,
                         23889, 23861, 23879, 23884,
                         23856, 19920, 19898, 23916,
                         23894, 20985, 23930, 20932,
                         20986, 22434, 20021, 19893,
                         19903, 19707, 19935 )
       AND calendar.vscdate = Str_to_date('25-10-2011', "%e-%c-%Y")
       AND segments.segmentstart >= Str_to_date('15:56', "%H:%i")
       AND routes.routeservicetype = 0
       AND segments.segmentstart > "00:00:00"
ORDER  BY segments.segmentstart
```

what are things I can do to speed this up? any tips are welcome, i'm pretty new to sql...
but I can't change the structure of the db because it's not mine...

Comment: Your query looks good to me. If you have indexes on the stopid and segmentstart columns should be blazing fast.

Comment: Have you done a describe on the query yet? What does it tell you? What indexes do you have in place? What database engine are you using?

Comment: @icarus I've put indexes there but it didn't help at all :s

Comment: @rwilliams engine i innodb and i put indexes on trips.vsid, calendar.vscdate, segments.segmentstart and routes.routeservicetype(thanks Guffa) and this is what DESCRIBE says but I don't know what to make out of it...http://i.imgur.com/ZOm4p.jpg

Comment: This part seems illogical: AND segments.segmentstart >= Str_to_date('15:56', "%H:%i") AND segments.segmentstart > "00:00:00"
You could try to remove the ORDER, maybe it would give some improvements.

Comment: that's because some segments have a segmentstart of "00:00:00" but I don't need to show those...

Comment: OH WOW!!! removing the order by takes the query from 7.7 seconds to 0.5 seconds....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the query, I would say that you should make sure that you have indexes on `trips.vsid`, `calendar.vscdate`, `segments.segmentstart` and `routes.routeservicetype`. I assume that there is already indexes on all the primary keys in the tables.

Using `explain` as Briedis suggested would show you how well the indexes work.

You might want to add covering indexes for some tables, like for example an index on `trips.vsid` where `tripid` and `routeid` are included. That way the database can use only the index for the data that is needed from the table, and not read from the actual table.

#### Edit:

The execution plan tells you that it successfully uses indexes for everything except the `segments` table, where it does a table scan and filters by the `where` condition. You should try to make a covering index for `segments.segmentstart` by including `tripid` and `stopid`.

Comment: adding indexes to segments.segmentstart actually slowed it down :s

Comment: @mars: That can happen if you already have a similar index that the database can use, and it thinks that the newly added index looks better but is in fact worse.

Comment: @mars how does EXPLAIN output look now?

Comment: @mars: I added a suggestion above based on the execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

Use EXPLAIN to find the bottlenecks: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html
Then perhaps, add indexes.

If you don't need to select ALL rows, use LIMIT to limit returned result count.

Comment: I did a describe and got this result, but I don't really know what to make out of it...i.imgur.com/ZOm4p.jpg

Comment: You have 12 million rows in segmets. Do you really need to select so much? What are you doing with the result?

Comment: no this query return only 1000 rows but the number of rows is variable depending on date, time and those stopids

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a clusters index to the `routes` table on both `routeservicetype` and `routeid`.

Depending on the frequency of the data within the `routeservicetype` field, you may get an improvement by shrinking the amount of data being compared in the join to the trips table.

Looking at the explain plan, you may also want to force the sequence of the table usage by using `STRAIGHT_JOIN` instead of `JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`), as I've had real improvements with this technique.

Essentially, put the table with the smallest row-count of extracted data at the beginning of the query, and the largest row count table at the end (in this case possibly the `segments` table?), with the exception of simple lookups (eg. for descriptions).

You may also consider altering the `WHERE` clause to filter the `segments` table on `stopid` instead of the `stops` table, and creating a clustered index on the `segments` table on (`stopid`, `tripid` and `segmentstart`) - this index will be effectively able to satisfy two joins and two where clauses from a single index...

To build the index...

```
ALTER TABLE segments ADD INDEX idx_qry_helper ( stopid, tripid, segmentstart );
```

And the altered `WHERE` clause...

```
WHERE  segments.stopid IN ( 43914, 23899, 23925, 23908,
                     23913, 19899, 23871, 43902,
                     23876, 25563, 18956, 19912,
                     23889, 23861, 23879, 23884,
                     23856, 19920, 19898, 23916,
                     23894, 20985, 23930, 20932,
                     20986, 22434, 20021, 19893,
                     19903, 19707, 19935 )
         :
         :
```

At the end of the day, a 10 second response for what appears to be a complex query on a fairly large dataset, isn't all that bad!